# Colspan and Rowspan attribute in html work opposite?

Tags: html, html-table

Why colspan and rowspan work opposite in html table?

This is how a table works.

[Picture of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEJN2.png)

In HTML colspan work on rows of html table.

[Colspan working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJr2R.png)

And same goes for rowspan. By name COLSPAN suggest column span but in working it span row and "rowspan" span columns in html table.

Comment: You got it all wrong.The name colspan means that over how many columns should the row span over. And vice versa for rowspan

Answer (score 2):

It's not working opposite. Colspan means that the cell will span a certain number of columns, so if you put colspan = "3" that cell will take up 3 columns in the row, which is what your image shows.

In this image the columns are marked A, B, C, D, etc., the rows are numbered.

[image: column and row spanning]

The blue spans columns A, B, and C of row 1. This is what colspan does.
The green spans rows 3 to 6 of column A. This is what rowspan does.

Comment: Let say colspan means that the cell will span a certain number of columns and columns by definition means start from top to down. so, if i put colspan = '3' it should take 3 cell from top to down but instead it take 3 cell from left to right(row by definition means start from left to right). I think their is mistake in naming.

Comment: @SarabNadeem See the update to my answer.